# SQL query that sorts by the Sum number of values per category

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running a tag-based web gallery on PHP and MySQL. I'm not an expert in SQL, I have a basic understanding but not more than that.
There is an option to enable "tag categories" which basically enables using tags like so:
animal:cat,
animal:dog

When editing a picture's tags, there is an option to sort the tag categories in an alphabetical order, using this query:

```
 SELECT tag, FLOOR(LN(LN(count - :tag_min1 + 1)+1)*150)/200 AS scaled, count
                                        FROM tags
                                        WHERE count >= :tag_min2
                                        ORDER BY CASE
                                            WHEN tag LIKE '%:%' THEN 1
                                            ELSE 2
                                        END, tag
                                        LIMIT :limit",
                        ["tag_min1" => $tags_min, "tag_min2" => $tags_min, "limit" => $max_count]
```

Which works fine, but I would like to add another level of sorting, for tag category size.

The database looks like this example:

```
Tag ID ---- Tag ---- Count
1 ---- animal:dog ---- 30
2 ---- animal:cat ---- 15
3 ---- object:car ---- 55
4 ---- object:train ---- 25
```

I want the query above to sort (descending) by the amount of tags (count) a **category** has, not the tag itself.
Meaning **animal** category has 30+15 = 45 tags, and **object** category has 55+25 = 80 tags, so object category should be first.

I'm working with MySQL version  8.0.23

Thanks!

EDIT:
Sharing sample data:
[image: Database screenshot]

Comment: Provide **precise** MySQL version. *I tried working on this with the string_split function* There is no such function in MySQL.

Comment: please share sample data with create table and insert script.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I edited the question and added a screenshot
Furthermore I must have got some thing confused regarding the string split part, because I found a guide that made that function. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY SUM(`Count`) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(Tag, ':', 1)) DESC
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c5ce9c06f8acf562f1dd6f136d30735)

Comment: Thank you!
ORDER BY SUM(count) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(tag, ':', 1)) DESC worked like a charm.

Thank you SO much!